# Use alias defined in a with-clause in a where-clause of a Neo4jclient query

Tags: c#, neo4j, cypher, neo4jclient

I want to create a query in neo4jclient for this cypher query:

```
MATCH (price:Item)-->(item:Item)
WHERE (item.Id = 2)
WITH item, max(price.Timestamp) AS maxDate
MATCH (price:Item)-->(item:Item)
WHERE (price.Timestamp = maxDate)
RETURN price
```

I already came up with this piece of code:

```
_graphClient.Cypher
        .Match("(price:Price)-->(item:Item)")
        .Where((Item item) => item.Id == 2)
        .With((price, item) => new 
           {
             item, 
             maxDate = Return.As<DateTimeOffset>("max(price.Timestamp)")
           })
        .Match("(price:Price)-->(item:Item)")
        .Where((Price price) => price.Timestamp == Return.As<DateTimeOffset>("maxDate"))
        .Return(price=> price.As<Price>())
```

but this returns the maxDate alias in qoutes:

```
MATCH (price:Item)-->(item:Item)
WHERE (item.Id = 2)
WITH item, max(price.Timestamp) AS maxDate
MATCH (price:Item)-->(item:Item)
WHERE (price.Timestamp = "maxDate") <--
RETURN price
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried just `Where("price.Timestamp = maxDate")` ?

Comment: Hmm didn't knew the possibility. It will do. Ain't a beauty, but then again .. so isn't the Return.As<...>("max(price.Timestamp")). Make it an answer and i'll accept it. Thanx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code wise the `Return.As` statements are used to Help `Neo4jClient` know what to parse the results as (when used in a `Return` statement) and `With` is treated in the same way.

When they're used, they output the `Cypher` you see (so `"max.Timestamp as maxDate"`), and `Return.As` will always output that style of response :/

The only way I know of to get the `Where` the way you want is via `Where("price.Timetamp = maxDate")`, using the string overload.